# Server rejects request on self hosted service

Tags: vb.net, wcf, hosting, self

I have created a self hosted service with a proxy
Service and Contracts

```
Namespace ECDBDatabase.Service
Public Class DatabaseService
    <ServiceContract(Name:="DatabaseService",      Namespace:="net.tcp://localhost:9010/ECDBDatabase.Service")> _
    Public Interface IRPMSDatabaseService
<OperationContract()> _
        Function GetHandover(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As DataSet
End Interface

  Public Function GetHandover(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As DataSet Implements IRPMSDatabaseService.GetHandover
            'Connection string to Database
            Dim ReadConnectionString As String = "data source =localhost;" + "User ID=" & Username + ";Password=" & Password + ";Database=somedatabase"
            ReadConnection = New SqlConnection(ReadConnectionString)
            'Fill and return the dataset
            Try
                dbScriptFile = "some sql file"
                objReader = New StreamReader(dbScriptFile)
                cmd.CommandText = objReader.ReadToEnd.Replace("Go", ";")
                scriptArr = cmd.CommandText.Split(";")
                cmd.Connection = ReadConnection
                HandoverDataset = New DataSet
                HandoverAdapter = _
                    New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

                For i = 0 To scriptArr.Length - 1
                    cmd.CommandText = scriptArr.GetValue(i)
                    'Fill the dataset
                    HandoverAdapter.Fill(HandoverDataset)
                Next
                'Return the dataset.

                Return HandoverDataset
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Function
        End Class
       End Class
End Namespace
```

My host is as follows:

```
 Sub Main()
    'Instantiate the service address
    Dim baseAddress As Uri = New Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9010/ECDBDatabase.Service")
    'Create the servicehost
    Using ECDBHost As New ServiceHost(GetType(ECDBService.ECDBDatabase.Service.DatabaseService.RPMSDatabaseService), baseAddress)

        Dim smb As New ServiceMetadataBehavior
        Dim debug As New ServiceDebugBehavior
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = False
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15
        debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = True

        ECDBHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb)

        ECDBHost.Open()

        'Execute commands on console application
        Console.WriteLine("Service has started at {0}", baseAddress)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Using
End Sub
```

My Proxy is as follows;

```
 Public Function GetHandover(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As DataSet
        Try
            HandoverDataset = New DataSet

            tempBinding = New NetTcpBinding()
            tempAddress = New EndpointAddress(New Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9010/ECDBDatabase.Service"), New SpnEndpointIdentity(""))
            With tempBinding

            End With
            With tempAddress

            End With
            'Instantiating the channel for the proxy and setting the proxy up to communicate
            tempFactory = New ChannelFactory(Of ECDBService.ECDBDatabase.Service.DatabaseService.IRPMSDatabaseService)(tempBinding, tempAddress)
            With tempFactory
                tempProxy = .CreateChannel()
            End With
            'Setting the contracts to the channel
            With tempProxy
                HandoverDataset = .GetHandover(UserName, Password)

            End With
            Return HandoverDataset
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
```

I call the proxy which in turns access the service and it is as follows:

```
 Private Sub frmHandover_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Load the dataset and bind the controls.
    Try
        HandoverData = New DatabaseProxyClass.ECDBDatabase.Service.DatabaseProxy

        User = frmEhawkRPMS.UserN
        Pass = frmEhawkRPMS.PassW
        HandoverSet = New DataSet
        HandoverSet = HandoverData.GetHandover(User, Pass)
```

My problem starts when I attempt to access the service from the proxy I get the following error: "Data Error: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults(either from servicebahviorattribute or from the  configuration behaviour) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft.net Framework 3.0 SDk documentation and inspect the server trace logs."
I've attemtped to enable the exceptions but get an error that says there is already a service behavior and it doesn't allow me to add the exceptiondetailfaults to the service behavior and there are not too many if any examples for adding this in a self hosted WCF with VB.
I'm looking for some advice on adding the exception in VB or if someone notice what my problem is to begin with and can point it out that would be greatly appreciated as well.
Also here is my app config that is in my console application that starts the service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
     <service name="ECDBService.ECDBDatabase.Service.RPMSDatabaseService">
       <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9010/ECDBDatabase.Service"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="ECDBService.ECDBDatabase.Service.IRPMSDatabaseService" />
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding"         contract="ECDBService.ECDBDatabase.Service.RPMSDatabaseService">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
    <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
    </services>     
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```